# How to actually execute this ISP dialer using C#?

Tags: c#, networking, network-programming

Well to connect to internet, I have to run a dialer provided by my ISP. Now the problem is that whenever I leave my pc overnight (for downloading purpose), the dialer disconnects (network failure or just random disconnection) and the downloading stops. This is very frustrating for me.

So I tried to code a C# program that will :

```
1. When you run it, it will start 30 minutes timer.
2. After 30 minutes, it will ping google to check if the net is connected or not.
3. If it is connected, no action will be performed and timer will again check after 30 minutes.
4. If it is not connected then it will execute my ISP's dailer. After connecting, it will again check after 30 minutes.
```

Now the problem is that I am very new to C# and can't code all that well. But I have managed to ping google successfully and display a related message box.

Here is the code that I have written so far :

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Net.NetworkInformation;
using System.Net;
using System.Diagnostics;

namespace WindowsFormsApplication3
{
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    Timer timer = new Timer();

    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        timer.Tick += new EventHandler(timer1_Tick); 
        timer.Interval = (1000) * (10);           
        timer.Enabled = true;                       
        timer.Start();                              
    }

    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        Ping ping = new Ping();

        PingReply pingStatus = ping.Send(IPAddress.Parse("208.69.34.231"));

        if (pingStatus.Status == IPStatus.Success)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Pinged Google Successfully");
        }
        else
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Can't Ping to Google.");
        }


    }

    private void timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Process.Start("C:\\WINDOWS\\system32\\rasphone.exe","-d DELTA1");
    }

}
}
```

Now I know this code is kinda messed up but it eventually does open my ISP dialer (Picture : http://s12.postimg.org/xscgsdcxp/untitled.jpg) but still I have to manually press that connect button in the dialer. How do I automate this button?

Also if someone could help me rearrange the code, I'd really appreciate it.

Thank You.

Regards,
Shajee A.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not entirely familiar with this but I think you want to use `rasdial DELTA1` instead of `rasphone -d DELTA1`. Rasdial is designed for unattended use while rasphone is designed to interact with a user. See this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11469514/difference-between-rasphone-exe-and-rasdial-exe).

You can click a button programmatically in a UI by using the UI Automation API, if it is supported. This is a very basic outline:

```
using System.Windows.Automation;

Process p = Process.Start("C:\\WINDOWS\\system32\\rasphone.exe","-d DELTA1");
Thread.Sleep(5000); // give the program some time to start.
var windowElement = AutomationElement.FromHandle(p.MainWindowHandle);
var connectButton = windowElement.FindFirst(TreeScope.Descendants, new PropertyCondition(AutomationElement.NameProperty, "Connect"));
var invokePattern = (InvokePattern)connectButton.GetCurrentPattern(InvokePattern.Pattern);
invokePattern.Invoke();
```

Of course, you may need some retry logic or error handling in there if, for example, the program starts with "Connect" disabled while it initializes and then enables it later.

As for your code, you want to do the ping in the timer callback. I'm guessing you have a button for testing. I think this would make more sense:

```
private void timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Ping ping = new Ping();
    PingReply pingStatus = ping.Send("www.google.com");

    if (pingStatus.Status != IPStatus.Success)
    {
        Process.Start("C:\\WINDOWS\\system32\\rasphone.exe","-d DELTA1");
        // automation logic here.
    }       
}
```